# registering UnhandledException of AppDomain WPF

Tags: wpf, unhandled-exception

I am registering to un-handled exception of my WPF Application.

After UnhandledExceptionHandler invokes, the application will close automatically ? Or do I need to call ShutdownProcess();

Is this enough ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Register to unhandled exception for this application
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;


    static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            Exception ex = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            _logger.ErrorFormat("Process caught unhandled exception, Exception = {0}", ex);
            ShutdownProcess();
        }
        catch
        {
            // swallow silently... nothing we can do.
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Application will close automatically if you don't set `e.Handled = true`. What was your question exactly ?

Comment: I dont have any e.Handled and this is not DispacherUnhandledException..

Comment: My question is - will my process be closed automatically ? will it display "ugly" OS popup window about crushing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx):

> "This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows
>   the application to log information about the exception before the
>   system default handler reports the exception to the user and
>   terminates the application."

So the ugly Popup will be displayed regardless what you are doing in your Handler and the application will be terminated after that.
If you don't want the default error popup to be displayed you should add a handler to `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` log your errors and call `Application.Current.Shutdown()` yourself.